# $_GET always returning admin

Tags: php, get, indexing, admin

I'm currently busy on my `index.php` to include the via `$_GET` requested file.
The only problem is that it is always returning `admin` and never returning the declared value in the `$_GET` variable.

All the files are in a directory used as subdomain.

`Warning: include(pages/admin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tjattern/domains/*censored*/public_html/admin/index.php on line 20`

I am requesting `http://admin.*censored*.nl/index.php?page=dashboard`

`index.php`

```
   <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// include required files
require_once('core/config.php');
require_once('template/tpl_top.php');


if(isset($_COOKIE['as']))
{
   if(isset($_GET['page']))
   {
      $file = "pages/".$_GET['page'].".php";
     if(file_exists($file))
     {
      include($file);  // actual line 20
     }
     else
     {
      echo 'This page could not be found';
     }
   }
   else
   {
      include('pages/dashboard.php');
   }
}
else
{
 include('pages/login.php');
}


require_once('template/tpl_bot.php');

?>
```

Comment: Is that the entire contents of index.php? If so the error is in another one of your files. You should probably check the file exists before trying to include by the way.

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? have you dumped out $_GET e.g. var_dump($_GET);? is your .htaccess rewriting your urls? Also you might what to wrap the include in is_file('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php'); to actually check the file exists.

Comment: Updated the code, inserted complete index.php - There is an htaccess in the main directory, does that also affect a sub directory? When I dump the var, it also gives me admin.

Comment: You haven't post the url you calling.

Comment: http://admin.*censored*.nl/index.php?page=dashboard -- updated topic

Comment: @JordiPrevost Hi Jordi - please don't update the post title to include "SOLVED". There's already a mechanism in stack overflow to show resolved/unresolved questions - and it just adds needless clutter for future views. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ww.example.com/index.php?page=sample

requesting this url

$_GET['page'] in index.php end will be "sample"

Are you passing correct values in page atribute?

Comment: Yes, I am passing the correct tributes to the script like your url does.

Comment: var_dump($_GET);exit;
put this code as the very beginning and check whether correct value comes or not

Comment: Still gives me the value `admin` it also gives me the value `admin` while not requesting `$_GET` method.

Comment: can you put the url here if its ok

Comment: change the get paramater page to pagep or any other and check

Comment: I've done the var_dump(); exit; that you told me. It echoes the requested parameter now.

Comment: then there must be something in the two requested files
require_once('core/config.php');
require_once('template/tpl_top.php');

Comment: put echo $_GET['page'] ; in every line starting from bigining. after testing put it after next chunk of code and see where it changes . trouble shoot from where it changes exactly !!

Comment: Problem solved for now, required to use inded.php?page= instead of /?page= since it will activate the root .htaccess

Comment: @JordiPrevost Could you please post your solution as an answer and mark your answer as correct? It'll help future viewers, so that they don't need to read through the comments. Cheers! :)